# spark data frame converting row values into column name

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Using spark dataframe i need to convert the row values into column and partition by user id and create a csv file.

```scala
val someDF = Seq(
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),
  ("user1", "physics","gravity","70"),
  ("user3", "biology","health","50"),
  ("user2", "biology","health","100"),
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","40"),
  ("user2", "physics","gravity-2","20")
).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")

someDF.show(false)

+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   90|
|  user1|  physics|    gravity|   70|
|  user3|  biology|     health|   50|
|  user2|  biology|     health|  100|
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   40|
|  user2|  physics|  gravity-2|   20|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+

val result = someDF.groupBy("user_id", "course_id").pivot("lesson_name").agg(first("score"))

result.show(false)

+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|  user3|  biology|     null|   null|     null|    50|
|  user1|     math|       90|   null|     null|  null|
|  user2|  biology|     null|   null|     null|   100|
|  user2|  physics|     null|   null|       20|  null|
|  user1|  physics|     null|     70|     null|  null|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
```

With the above code i'm able to convert row value(lesson_name) to column name.
But I need to save the out in csv in a `course_wise`

**Expected out in csv should be like this below formate.**

```scala
biology.csv // Expected Output

+-------+---------+------+
|user_id|course_id|health|
+-------+---------+------+
|  user3|  biology|  50  |
|  user2|  biology| 100  |
+-------+---------+-------

physics.csv // Expected Output

+-------+---------+---------+-------
|user_id|course_id|gravity-2|gravity|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
|  user2|  physics|  50     |  null |
|  user1|  physics| 100     |  70   | 
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

**Note: Each course in a csv it should contain only it's specifi lesson names and it should not contain any non relevant course lesson names.

Actually in csv i'm able to in below formate**

```scala
result.write
  .partitionBy("course_id")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save(somepath)
```

eg:

```scala
biology.csv // Wrong output, Due to it is containing non-relevant course lesson's(algebra-1,gravity-2,algebra-1)
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|  user3|  biology|     null|   null|     null|    50|
|  user2|  biology|     null|   null|     null|   100|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
```

**Anyone can help to solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 1):

Just filter by course before you pivot:

```
val result = someDF.filter($"course_id" === "physics").groupBy("user_id", "course_id").pivot("lesson_name").agg(first("score"))

+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|user_id|course_id|gravity|gravity-2|
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|user2  |physics  |null   |20       |
|user1  |physics  |70     |null     |
```

+-------+---------+-------+---------+

Comment: Why are you hardcoding "physics"? What if i have some 1000 course_id's ? how do we handle in that case ?

Comment: I wanted to create a course wise csv file? let's say i have some 1000 courses in that case and each course is having some 5 lesson's in that case how do you handle that? @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming you mean you'd like to save the data into separate directories by course_id. you can use this approach.

```
scala> val someDF = Seq(
("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),
("user1", "physics","gravity","70"),
("user3", "biology","health","50"),
("user2", "biology","health","100"),
("user1", "math","algebra-1","40"),
("user2", "physics","gravity-2","20")
).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")


scala> val result = someDF.groupBy("user_id", "course_id").pivot("lesson_name").agg(first("score"))

scala>     val eventNames = result.select($"course_id").distinct().collect() 
var eventlist =eventNames.map(x => x(0).toString)



for (eventName <- eventlist) {
val course = result.where($"course_id" === lit(eventName))
//remove null column

val row = course
.select(course.columns.map(c => when(col(c).isNull, 0).otherwise(1).as(c)): _*)
.groupBy().max(course.columns.map(c => c): _*)
.first

val colKeep = row.getValuesMap[Int](row.schema.fieldNames)
.map{c => if (c._2 == 1) Some(c._1) else None }
.flatten.toArray


var final_df = course.select(row.schema.fieldNames.intersect(colKeep)
.map(c => col(c.drop(4).dropRight(1))): _*)


final_df.show()

final_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(s"${eventName}")
}


+-------+---------+------+
|user_id|course_id|health|
+-------+---------+------+
|  user3|  biology|    50|
|  user2|  biology|   100|
+-------+---------+------+

+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|user_id|course_id|gravity|gravity-2|
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|  user2|  physics|   null|       20|
|  user1|  physics|     70|     null|
+-------+---------+-------+---------+

+-------+---------+---------+
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|
+-------+---------+---------+
|  user1|     math|       90|
+-------+---------+---------+
```

if it solves your purpose please accept the answer.HAppy Hadoop

Comment: What if i have another column(batchid) along with courseid ? Let's say i want to save on both courseid and batchid ? ```val someDF = Seq(
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","90","b1"),
  ("user1", "physics","gravity","70","b1"),
  ("user3", "biology","health","50","b2"),
  ("user2", "biology","health","100","b2"),
  ("user1", "math","algebra-1","40","b1"),
  ("user2", "physics","gravity-2","20","b3")
).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score","batch_id")```

Comment: I want create a csv file on both batchid and courseid out put should be like this  `+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+---------+                          
|user_id|course_id|algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health|course_id|
+-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+---------+
|  user2|  physics|     null|   null|       20|  null|b3.      |
----------------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: Will that not be a pefromance impact ? When we have huge courseid and batchid?

Comment: this is totally different question, so add a new question for this. and if its solve your problem please accept the answer.

Comment: and also add a proper data frame with an expected output.

Comment: This is not completely different question and i agree your answer works fine with above condition. But i'm looking some generic solution. Just i asked what if i have another column "batchid"? and what if i wanted to create a csv on both courseid and batchid basis? will that not be a performance impact ?

Comment: Sure I will create another question.

Comment: first adding question will make more understanding of the requirement. please accept the answer.

Comment: In your result why biology is having having all these lessons [algebra-1|gravity|gravity-2|health] ? It should have only "health" lesson. Ofcourse we can filter out before "piviot" convertion. But my question is if we having huge amount of courseid and batchid then will that impact on performance ?

Comment: @Manju I am just updating the Answer.

Comment: please check and let me know if you any more queries related to above output.

Comment: Yes Mahesh, This fine but one more clarification, right now you are doing for loop on courseid `(for (eventName <- eventlist) {})`right ? what if i want filter on more field ? let's say another column called `batchid` do i need to add one more for loop again? eg: `for (eventName <- eventlist) {
 for(batchid <- batchList){
  val course = result.where(col("course_id") === lit(eventName) && col(batchid) ===lit(batchlist))
 }
}`

Comment: `val courseids = someDF.select(col("course_id")).distinct().collect() val batchids = someDF.select(col("batchid")).distinct().collect(); var courseList = courseids.map(x => x(0).toString); var batchList = batchids.map(x => x(0).toString) for (courseId <- courseList) { for (batchId <- batchList) {val df = someDF.filter(col("course_id") === courseId && col("batchid") === batchId).groupBy("courseid", "batchid", ).pivot("lesson_name").agg(first("score")){df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("batchid", "courseid").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(url)}}`  I mean like this.

Comment: Can't we avoid that `forloop`?

Comment: yes we need to  "for loop" for batch id as well. I think there are always multiple ways to execute the same thing but I am only using for loop. you can explore another way.

Comment: could you please also accept this answer if its solve your purpose?